# Nginx - Rewrite using last url segment

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

My original url are like following:

```
http://example.com/lab/file.php?id=4&idl=42
```

I want to beautify it, making it also accessible through a url like following:

```
http://example.com/l/not/important/url/part/?id=4&idl=42
```

I tried with following code, but it doesn't work.

```
rewrite /l/.*/([^/]+)/?$ /lab/file.php$1 last;
```

How to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Anything after the `?` is the query string and cannot be rewritten using the `rewrite` directive. However, by default, `rewrite` will append the original query string anyway.

You can either rewrite any URI that begins with `/l/` or create a location for `/l/`, for example:

```
rewrite ^/l/ /lab/file.php last;
```

or:

```
location ^~ /l/ {
    rewrite ^ /lab/file.php last;
}
```

The `^~` modifier makes this prefix location take precedence over regex locations at the same level. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

In both cases, `rewrite` will append the original query string to the rewritten URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.